# ExactTarget detailed File Transfer error message

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

So I have this task in Automation studio in ExactTarget which it fails on of the steps, I just a get a simple message, "error has occurred", where can I see a more detailed error message so I actually know what the problem is ?

[image: error massage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the previously uploaded file was interrupted in the middle of being processed and hence was in a locked situation and couldn't be replaced by a new file.

Seems like the lock was resolved after two days.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'll need to contact SFMC support to get the details of the error.

However, here are a few File Transfer troubleshooting tasks:

- Make sure your filename matches the file on the FTP share.  Unlike other places in SFMC, the FTP shares and filenames are case-sensitive.
- Check to make sure it's not Download (get) when it should be Upload (put) or vice-versa.  Are you *getting* from the location specified or *putting*?
- If it's a custom File Location, verify the credentials outside the platform.